# How to include forward slash in IBM AIX vi search & replace

Tags: search, replace, vi, aix

I have a file that contains the string `~/adminscripts/stderrtrace.txt`, and I want to find it and delete it.

But here's the catch: I'm on IBM AIX, which doesn't use Linux's `vim`, it uses the old 80's `vi` from System V UNIX, and that variant does not support changing the field delimiter on the search and replace command as in `:s#~/adminscripts/stderrtrace.txt##`: the search delimiter **has to** be a slash. I already tried escaping the slashes with `:s/~\/adminscripts\/stderrtrace.txt//` and I get `Substitute pattern match failed`.

Getting `vim` installed is not an option because it is a production server.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have access to AIX anymore. I would expect your ``s/...\/...//`` version to work. maybe use `sed` instead? (no `-i` however(I think!)), Good luck.

Comment: I'll probably have to exit vi and use sed for this indeed. You can change the field delimiter there. It's unfortunate that IBM AIX's commands are so limited... but what elase am I going to do.

Comment: What version of AIX are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on 5.3 and 6.1.  /usr/bin/vi is shipped in bos.rte.edit and the level I tested the 5.3 version was 5.3.0.60.  But both of the usual methods works for me.

You can backslash quote the delimiter:

```
:s/\//x/g
```

or you can change the delimiter:

```
:s%/%x%g
```

and they both work at the levels I'm testing on.